# Use the url as a variable in my jinja2 template?

Tags: django, django-templates, jinja2

Is a way to use the slug in my template?

I have in my urls:

```py
path("cats/check/<int:pk>/lista", ObjetoListView.as_view(), name='posesiones_consulta'),
```

How can I access **int:pk** as a variable?

I want to evaluate this:

```
{% if cat.mom.id == pk %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You pass it to the context with:

```
class ObjectoListView(ListView):

    # …

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().get_context_data(
            *args,
            pk=self.kwargs['pk'],
            **kwargs
        )
```

If you however want to *filter* the list, you should do this at the database level, for example with:

```
class ObjectoListView(ListView):

    # …

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().get_queryset(*args, **kwargs).filter(
            mom__pk=self.kwargs['pk']
        )
```

It is not a good idea to filter in the template, since then the database will return *all* records and thus increase the *bandwidth* between the database and the application, and furthermore filtering at the database level is (nearly) always faster than filtering in the view or template.

Comment: Thanks, but which is faster if I plan to use my PC and not the internet?

Comment: @TommydoNascimiento: still a database. A database uses *indexes* and thus can often filter in *O(log n)* time, whereas a template/view will take linear time. If the number of objects grows (1'000+), then the difference can be seen by the page taking quite long to answer.